# How does the T budding grafting method provide contact between the cambium layers?

Tags: fruit-trees, technique, grafting

In a T budding technique of grafting fruit trees, how does the [cambium layer](https://www.britannica.com/science/cambium) of the bud come into contact with the cambium layer of the rootstock?

How does this great method have such a high success rate if there is no direct contact between the cambium layers?

The upside down T method is usually more recommended.

[Here](https://youtu.be/adkhSOOTjMg) is a great video that demonstrates this method.

[image]

This is the photo that I made that shows where I think there is contact between the cambium layers, let me know if I am correct or not:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is direct contact between the two cambium layers - the removed bud has cambium (meristematic tissue) exposed on the cut side, and the T cut made in the stem it's to be grafted to has the bark or exterior tissue peeled back to reveal the cambium prior to insertion of the bud, as clearly demonstrated in the video you linked with. Whether the T cut in the rootstock stem is upside down or right side up, the principle is still the same.

In the UK, T budding is generally used on roses, and that's the only time I ever came across this method - trees are more often chip budded. In the case of roses, its usual to remove woody material from the back of the bud prior to inserting into the T shape on the rootstock.

[T-budding (Royal Horticultural Society)](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Advice/Profile?pid=399)

Comment: So where is the contact, on the sides or on the top-bottom?

Comment: all the way up - if you watch your video, you can see the exposed meristematic tissue on the bud where its been cut,  and you see the bark being folded back to reveal the cambium on the stem of the rootstock, prior to insertion

Comment: I made a photo with the red lines showing the contact of the cambium layers, let me know if it is correct https://i.imgur.com/3tDRszh.jpg

Comment: Yea, looks about right, though obviously, I can't see the cut bud you made as its already inserted; but its a  little confusing, that image - usually, the peeled back bark is folded back over after insertion, then taped, I'm not seeing any bark folded back over, did you peel the bark back on the rootstock stem round the T cut?

Comment: look in my website my gallery: https://www.mpoliasma.top/page3.php the photo was taken 1 month after grafting

Comment: Oh right, I see - and the other pic is when you first did it, presumably... that bud (2nd photo) looks healthy and swollen...which is good

Comment: yeah, as i remember i left some wood on the bud. It is second year since i grafted that and it has around 10 lemons. It has grapefruit, lemon and orange on it. The first and second photos are like 1-2 months after grafting

Comment: So it worked then...!

Comment: i grafted today, by looking at the photos with the grafts and temperature what do you believe is the chance for success? https://imgur.com/a/YwjjF

Comment: One can never know - looks good in the photo, but  if you're in the northern hemisphere, its a bit late in the season, depends where you  are. These things are always a wait and see anyway

Comment: Click the link i posted before, there is a photo with the temperature of my area

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68925/discussion-between-bamboo-and-csandreas1).

Comment: Sorry for necroing the question, but this isn't clear... bark is not removed from the scion, leaving these layers: stock wood, scion cambium, **scion bark**, stock cambium, stock bark. Do you mean that cambium contact only happens once the scion cambium swells past its own bark, or the bark shrinks, or something?